# Trust not granted error in full trust xbap application

Tags: wpf, xbap

I develop a xbap application with a full trust . But when i run it on another computer . It gives me the error " trust not granted" I also install the certificate on that computer but problem did not gone . How to solve this problem ??
I also import that certificate in " Trusted publisher " in internet explorer but the problem no gone ?
wot can i do to solve this problem ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i find the solution .I jut add the application URL in trusted sites . this fixs my problem